# WMP Screen Capture via right click

Tags: windows-xp, screen-capture, windows-media-player

I want to capture an image inside of WMP via a right-click selection.

A friend says she used to be able to do so, and wants to be able to do so again.

alt+printscreen is not an option - to complicated for dumb user. Alt-Print Screen/edit blank picutre/crop... too complicated.

We'd also prefer not to introduce another program (Although a small/simple/free one would be worth a try)

Cntr+I isn't working. Video-Overlay disable isn't working. Other attempts to get screen-captures working again have been for naught...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not play the video in [VLC](http://www.videolan.org/vlc/) and take video stills in [VLC](http://www.videolan.org/vlc/)?

- [How to Capture a Still Image From a Video (in VLC)](http://www.ehow.com/how_2142404_capture-still-image-video.html).  (Simple guide, tried it myself) (*Note*: in step 4, "Settings" is no "Tools". everything else works)

Read more: How to Capture a Still Image From a Video | eHow.com http://www.ehow.com/how_2142404_capture-still-image-video.html#ixzz1269c7d1X

---

You could always try a 'normal' screenshot program...suggestions below:

Lifehacker article: [The Five Best Screen Capture Tools.](http://lifehacker.com/5218155/five-best-screen-capture-tools)

Browse all the posts tagged ["screen-capture" at Lifehacker](http://lifehacker.com/tag/screen-capture/) for more free solutions...

Comment: ending up having reinstall WMP, MS Plus and something else... voting up because I suggested other software as well.